# Why WScript.Shell may be silently ignored in VBS?

Tags: shell, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

Here is a simple `test.vbs` file

```
Msgbox "Start" 
Set ws= CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
cDir = ws.CurrentDirectory  
Msgbox cDir
```

The above code works fine when I simply double click on the `test.vbs` file icon. However when I include this file in the `Windows Task Scheduler` and run it from there , `WScript.Shell` gets silently ignored . No error is thrown. I can see the first message "Start" . But the second one does not show up .   Why is it happening ?

Comment: Works for me ... I get system32 folder

Comment: Is it because of the typo? `"WSript.Shell"`

Comment: I think that might be the reason ... when I tested, I corrected the typo.

Comment: I am sorry. There is no typo in my file. I only mistypes the question in here , otherwise it would  not work as i double click the icon either .

Comment: Anyway . If it works on your computers then this must be the issue with my Windows7. Something that prevents shell

Comment: Sounds strange as you have said that first message appears ... means your script was executed by the task. But then it may be failing to create an object in task mode. Never heard of this issue before. Interesting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your task in windows task scheduler try: C:\Windows\Syswow64\cscript.exe "C:\Path to your vbs\yourvbs.vbs"